# Digitalocean Spaces Laravel App - Missing region

Tags: php, laravel, storage, digital-ocean

I am getting the following error:

```
Missing required client configuration options: region: (string) A “region” configuration value is required for the “s3” service (e.g., “us-west-2”).
```

Here is my setup (XXX to hide my creds):

.env file:

```
DO_SPACES_KEY=XXXXX
DO_SPACES_SECRET=XXXX
DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT=https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com
DO_SPACES_REGION=NYC3
DO_SPACES_BUCKET=XXXX
```

filesystems.php file (under the disks):

```
 'do_spaces' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('XXXXX'),
        'secret' => env('XXXXX'),
        'endpoint' => env('https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com'),
        'region' => env('NYC3'),
        'bucket' => env('XXXXXX'),
        ],
```

Also in filesystems.php file:

```
‘cloud’ => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD’, 'do_spaces’),
```

in the view file:

```
function addDocument(Request $req, $projId)
{
       
        $image = $req->file('uploadFile');


        $file_name = pathinfo($image->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);

        $input['imagename'] = $file_name.'_'.time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        //$destinationPath = public_path('/images');

        //$image->move($destinationPath, $input['imagename']);

        $destinationPath = $image->store('/', 'do_spaces');
        Storage::setVisibility($destinationPath, 'public');

        //$data = array('fid'=>$folderId,'fileLoc'=>$input['imagename'],'projId'=>$projId);
        //\DB::table('documents')->insert($data);

return back();

}
```

As you can see in the view, I try to store the image on the space and then store the path in the DB which would represent the path to the space.

I cannot get this error to go away; do you see any issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'region' => env('NYC3'),` should be `'region' => env('DO_SPACES_REGION'),`